# Maintain Placeholder when Tabbing through Input Fields | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, watermark

I am using this jQuery Watermark Input Plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/watermark-input-plugin/

I would like to keep the placeholder text visible when I tab through the fields. And only disappear when I click the field.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the js file for the watermark plugin, you will see at the end a group of functions and then

```
input.focus(clearMessage);
input.blur(insertMessage);                                
input.change(insertMessage);
```

if you change the focus to click, it should work like you want.

```
input.click(clearMessage);
input.blur(insertMessage);                                
input.change(insertMessage);
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jTUzv/

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers you can just put a "placeholder" attribute on the input field.

The placeholder text will be displayed if the input has focused (either tabbed to or clicked on) but then will go away once you have started to type something.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jTUzv/

Comment: 1. thats not the answer to the question. 2. Perhaps OP has to support IE6? 3. adding empty jsfiddle links?

Comment: Opps, fixed link.  And yea, doesn't work if you want to support old browsers.

Comment: I think I'll post an example to show how I got my version working. I'm still puzzled how to keep the placeholder text visible when tabbing through the fields, but removed when clicked. I'm sure it's impossible :)